# How to send Mongodb data response from model to app.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

models/test.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Test');

var LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  logs: String,
  trasaction_id: String,
  stage:String,
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var log = mongoose.model('Log', LogSchema);

exports.find_log = function(req,res){
  log.update(
    { transaction_id:req.id }, 
    { $set: { logs:req.note, stage:req.stage, transaction_id: req.id } }, 
    function(err, result) {
      return result;
    }
  );
}
```

app.js:

```
var log = require('./models/test');
var logdetails = log.find_log({id: "55cd20ea304efb0c3be95538",note: "Provisioning has completed, 2) IS_REACHABLE is in progress",stage: 3});
```

Error: `each time logdetails getting **undefined**`

I am getting the data from mongodb, but not able to send that mongodb data into app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Test');

var LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  logs: String,
  trasaction_id: String,
  stage:String,
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var log = mongoose.model('Log', LogSchema);

exports.find_log = function(req, cb){
  log.update(
    { transaction_id:req.id }, 
    { $set: { logs:req.note, stage:req.stage, transaction_id: req.id } }, 
    cb
  );
}
```

//app.js:

```
var log = require('./models/test');
var logdetails = log.find_log({
  id: "55cd20ea304efb0c3be95538",
  note: "Provisioning has completed, 2) IS_REACHABLE is in progress",
  stage: 3
}, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the reply.But still i am getting **undefined** when trying to console.log(logdetails)...also when I am doing console.log(JSON.stringify(res))..getting the result result:{"ok":1,"nModified":0,"n":0}....I am not sure what I am doing wrong..any help would be appreciated on this !!

Comment: `logdetails` is supposed to be undefined, that's not a mistake. find_log() is asynchronous, it does not have a traditional return value and will hence return `undefined`. You have to use callbacks, which is what I demonstrated in my answer. `console.log(res)` logs the result of the `log.update` function, what you're seeing there is standard Mongo output.

Comment: Yes, I followed your step whatever you mentioned in your answer. But in app.js file when I am doing logdetails(function(data){ console.dir(data);}) getting **undefined** I am not able to print full object any way..Please let me know if you need more details from me..Thanks

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. You are performing a Mongo UPDATE, you are getting `{"ok":1,"nModified":0,"n":0}`, this is the correct output of an update query. If you are trying display the log, then you should use a `find` query instead of an `update` query.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding.I need to update the object as well as I need the updated object. So, I was thinking wrong. I was thinking that I will be getting the updated object with update query. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.Let me try with find. It's really helpful to get input from you.Thanks!!